# How to add multiple listviews to Single activity in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have been trying to get a specific layout for more than two days now and really struck with it,
what am trying to achieve is:

To have a layout like the following

LISTVIEW A

VIEW

LISTVIEW B

VIEW

LISTVIEW C

(VIEWS are basically for headers)

Can any one help to sort out this task?

Comment: You are looking for an activity with 3 list views?

Comment: You just add three <ListViews../> to your xml layout (LinearLayout, vertical orientation). Where are you stuck at?

Comment: I need three listviews to one single activity , and they should scroll as single listview .>= at the end it has to look like single listview , with three different set of lists. is it clear.

Comment: 3 List views in one activity is just plain wrong. There must be a better way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 3 ListViews but a single ListView with a more complex Adapter. Check this question: [View like android's contact screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684022/view-like-androids-contact-screen) and follow the advice in the only answer.

Comment: I got the code from commons ware, but but i am not getting how to run demo ?

Comment: that's not a demo, it's an adapter, a .java to include (copy&paste) in your project. You'll need to learn how to use adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent activity with three fragment placeholders. Then, create three fragments each holding one of the listviews and use a fragmentmanager to start them.